# Corda 4.1 Unable to determine which flow to use

Tags: corda

After updating to Corda 4.1 from 3.3, when I run the node with deployNodes I get the following error:

`[main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Unable to determine which flow to use when responding to: com.example.CreateDealFlow.Sender. [com.example.CreateDealFlow.Receiver, com.example.CreateDealFlow.Receiver] are all registered with equal weight. [errorCode=mnl04m, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.1/mnl04m]`

there is no any information when I go through URL in error.

My flow looks something like this(I have simplified the code and removed custom logics, just what matters for this case is there)

```
    object CreateDealFlow {

    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByService
    class Sender(private val dataHolder: DealDataHolder) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            val sender = PartyAndCompany(dataHolder.senderUUID, ourIdentity)
            val receiver = PartyAndCompany(dataHolder.receiverUUID, getPartyFromX500String(dataHolder.receiverX500String))

            val txBuilder = buildTransaction(sender = sender, receiver = receiver)
            txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

            val partiallySignedTransaction = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
            val parties = partiallySignedTransaction.tx.outputStates.first().participants
            val (fullySignedTx, flowSessions) = collectSignaturesFromReceivers(partiallySignedTransaction, parties)

            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, flowSessions, FinalityFlow.tracker()))
        }

        @Suspendable
        fun buildTransaction(sender: PartyAndCompany, receiver: PartyAndCompany): TransactionBuilder {

        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(CreateDealFlow.Sender::class)
    class Receiver(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {


        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {

                override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {

                }

            }

            val txWeJustSigned = subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
            return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartyFlow, expectedTxId = txWeJustSigned.id))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try do a gradle `clean`, `build` and `deployNodes`. That looks weird.

Comment: I tried many times but the problem stays the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved by Andranik himself

The issue was due to having 3 CorDapps (`workflows`, `contracts`, `workflows-2`).

`workflows-2` depends on `workflows`. To do so it was using a `compile` dependency. When `delpoyNodes` was run this was building in the `workflows` code into `workflows-2` (a.k.a fat jarring). This then failed at runtime since there were now two CorDapps that contained a flow found in `workflows`.

To resolve this, `cordaCompile` was used. This included the `workflows` module as a compile time dependency but does not build it into the jar. When the node is ran, the flow is loaded from the `workflows` CorDapp and loaded onto the classpath where `workflows-2` can now also access it.